# Problem Alphas Help

Tags: transparency, sculpt

Problems with alpha blending. displayed on the other side. Why is that?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6KJnj.png)

[image]

Comment: https://scontent.fiev25-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.15752-0/p480x480/72841168_416617042389658_1131021470659510272_n.png?_nc_cat=103&_nc_oc=AQnAg1jHr6-4P734eT8-NvIQjHDbwPbuhF4gIQA-NqN5YBw9Kd4ghwjsw_I326RkI1s&_nc_ht=scontent.fiev25-1.fna&oh=56c02a84c7881bd05fd438b3695dcd8c&oe=5E1D3C17

Comment: Under the brush tool there is an options menu.Open it and check in "Front Faces Only".